# XNA - Non perspective projection?

Tags: xna, isometric, projection

For a section of my game, instead of having a perspective projection, i would like to display an isometric view of an object.

So i don't want things to appear smaller if in a distance, etc.

Basically a proper isometric image.

Is there any way to do this in XNA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign any arbitrary matrix to the pipeline's projection matrix in XNA, even one that doesn't perform a useful projection (you probably won't see useful results doing that, but you *can*).

So you can construct an orthographic projection matrix yourself or use one of [XNA's helper methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.createorthographic.aspx) and use that. You'll also have to adjust the view matrix to position the camera from the angle you want, of course.

Answer (score 1):

[Matrix.CreateOrthographic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195662.aspx) should do the trick.